# How to start sharing action from pop-up menu for listview defined in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, share

I am trying to share coupon code through "Share" option that comes in pop-up menu (Check snapshot on how my app looks and where "Share" option is). But my application getting crashed. I don't know if I need to do anything on AndroidManifest to start sharing action. Please help.
1. My Adapter code (Please check code under popup.setOnMenuItemClickListner Method)

```
    package com.trillbit.retail.activity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.trillbit.retail.R;

/**
 * Created by shashikant.burnwal on 12-29-2016.
 */

public class PlaceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Place>{
    final Context mContext;
    int mLayoutResourceID;
    Place mData[]=null;

    public PlaceAdapter(Context context, int resource, Place[] data) {
        super(context, resource, data);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mLayoutResourceID = resource;
        this.mData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public Place getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row=convertView;
        PlaceHolder holder=null;
        //row initialization
        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            row=inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceID,parent,false);
            holder=new PlaceHolder();
            holder.nameView=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
            holder.offerView=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.zipcodeTextView);
            holder.imageView=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            holder.menuButton=(ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.menu_button);
            row.setTag(holder);



        }else{
            holder=(PlaceHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        Place place=mData[position];
        holder.nameView.setText(place.mPlace);
        holder.offerView.setText(String.valueOf(place.mOffer));
        int resID=mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(place.mImage,"drawable",mContext.getPackageName());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(resID);


        //menuButton Activity

        holder.menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.popupMenuStyle);
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper,view);

                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list,popup.getMenu());
                popup.show();

                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                        switch(item.getItemId()){
                            case R.id.share:
                                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                                String shareBody = "Use Coupon Code Trill05";
                                String shareSub = "Exclusive 15% Discount";
                                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareSub);
                                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                                sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
                                return true;
                            case R.id.show_coupon:
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setClass(getContext(), CouponActivity.class);
                                Bundle bunde = new Bundle();
                                bunde.putString("coupon","Here is Coupon");
                                intent.putExtras(bunde);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                return true;
                            case R.id.like:
                                return true;
                            default:
                                return true;

                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        });


        return row;

    }

    private static class PlaceHolder{
        TextView nameView;
        TextView offerView;
        ImageView imageView;
        ImageButton menuButton;

    }
}
```

2. AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:supportsRtl="true"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
       <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
           </intent-filter>

       </activity>

       <activity android:name=".activity.ProductsActivity"/>

       <activity android:name=".activity.CouponActivity"
                 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert"
                 android:label="@string/coupon"/>
   </application>
   ```
3. Image:

[image]

Comment: `my application getting crashed` please share crash logs

Comment: can you post your crash error from logcat?

Comment: Logcat showing 70 pages error, so I am not sure what to post here. However last 4 lines I am adding here.01-08 02:03:36.899 14419-14419/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-08 02:03:36.899 14419-14419/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-08 02:11:43.956 1135-1135/? E/installd: eof
01-08 02:11:43.956 1135-1135/? E/installd: failed to read size

Answer (score 0):

My Problem got solved by changing initialization of adapter constructor. Earlier I was initializing my adapter as

```
mPlaceAdapter = new PlaceAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.row, mPlaces);
```

But after changing getActivity().getBaseContext() to only getActivity() solved my issue.